# Oracle jdk checksums are wrong

Tags: java, md5, checksum

I have been trying to download the latest JDK for windows, jdk-8u121-windows-x64.exe, at:
 http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

The page links to a checksum page listing all of the MD5 and SHA-256 checksums for all of the various JDK downloads:
 https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/s/digest/8u121checksum.html

The checksums for jre-8u121-windows-x64.exe do not match. I have tried downloading 3 times. The checksums listed are: 
sha256: 6741acefeb3845964534b3821d459b95c7dfa079f104c5041d1f95d3b6b7a502
md5: a963c6b8a012e658a3d657c4897cf7c8

I had downloaded maven from the Maven site prior to this and its checksum did match, so the problem is not with my checksum calculations. I use two different tools for this.

What should one do in this case? (I tried calling the phone number listed at the bottom of the page, but it was just a long message for getting in touch with various Oracle Sales departments.) Should I go ahead and install it anyway?

Other questions that come to mind: Am I the only developer in the world who bothers to check checksums? If these are not important to check, then why does Oracle bother publishing them?

Comment: You said you downloaded `jdk-8u121-windows-x64.exe` but then you talk about the checksums for `jre-8u121-windows-x64.exe` (note: JRE, not JDK), and you've quoted the checksums for the JRE, not the JDK. I can confirm that the checksums are correct for the JDK (further up the page). You're just comparing with the wrong checksums, which is easily done when the names are so similar.

Comment: You are right. I hadn't even noticed that.

Comment: You can just delete the question, it's probably not going to be useful to others in the future. :-)